# finding the beginning node of a loop in a linked list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

How to find the beginning node of a loop in a given linked list ? Let's call this the **cycle point**

So far, I've understand the following (using slow/fast pointer):

1. Assume list has a non-looped part of size `k`
2. slow moves k steps
3. fast moves 2k steps
4. fast is (2k - k)= `k` steps `ahead` of slow
5. slow is at the beginning of loop; also known as `Cycle point`
6. fast is `(LOOP_LENGTH - k)` steps `behind` from `Cycle point` or slow pointer at this point
7. for each 1 step slow moves, fast moves 2 steps and gains on slow by 1 step.
8. Thus, it would take fast `(LOOP_LENGTH - k)` steps to meet slow and collide
9. This is the step I don't understand: 
   **At this collision point, both nodes will be `k` steps from the front of the loop.**
10. Once the collision point is found, move one pointer to the head of list.
11. Now move both pointers at the speed of 1 step / turn till the collide. The node at which they both meet is the beginning of the the loop and hence the `Cycle point`

Can someone please explain me step 9 and after that ?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

One thing I'd like to point out is, once inside the loop, fast will never overtake slow pointer. They will collide. Here's why: slow is at i and fast is assuming at i-1. when they move, slow=> i+1 and fast will be at i+1 too, hence collision. OR, slow is at i and fast is at i-2. next move, slow-> i+1; fast: i. next move, slow-> i+2, fast: i+2 and hence collision again. so fast will never be able to overtake slow, only collide once inside the loop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 6. is wrong, the fast pointer is still k steps away from the slow pointer which is at the cycle point at that time; but better use ***ahead*** or ***behind*** instead of *away*. Plus, `k` may be smaller, bigger, or equal to the `loop_length`.

So, the fast pointer is `k` steps ahead of a slow one when that's reached the loop point which is, at your supposition, `k` steps after the start. Now, measuring on a loop, the fast pointer is `k % loop_length` steps ahead of the loop point. Right? If `k = some_n * loop_length + r`, the fast pointer is `r` steps ahead of the loop point, which is to say, `r := k % loop_length` steps ahead.

But that means that the slow pointer is `loop_length - r` steps ***ahead of the fast one***, along the loop. This is a *loop* after all. So after `loop_length - r` additional steps the fast pointer will catch on to the slow one. For each step the slow pointer moves away, the fast moves closer in by *two* steps.

So we don't know `k`, we don't know `loop_length` or `r`, we only know `m = k + loop_length - r = some_n * loop_length + r + loop_length - r = (some_n+1) * loop_length`. The total number of steps `m` until the two pointers' meeting point, is a multiple of the loop length.

So now we start over, with a new pointer at the start and the slow where it met the fast, `m` steps ahead of the new. We move the new and the slow at equal speed, by 1 step at each time, and at the cycle point they shall meet - because when the new pointer has reached the cycle point, the second is still `m` steps ahead, which is to say, `m % loop_length == 0` steps ahead along the loop. That way we find out what `k` is (we count our steps all the time), and the cycle point.

And we find `loop_length` by going along the loop one more time, until the two meet one more time.

- see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Algorithms

Comment: can you explain this relationship `m = k + loop_length - r = some_n * loop_length + r + loop_length - r = (some_n+1) * loop_length` ?

Comment: I've just substituted the values. :) The total number of steps until the two pointers meet, what is it? We said we have `k` steps until the cycle point; when slow is at `k`, fast is `r = k % loop_length` ahead of the slow; i.e. **slow is `loop_length - r` ahead of the fast** - because the slow stands at the cycle point, if we add distances from it to fast, and then from fast towards it, we get `loop_length`. That's what having a *loop* means. And `r = k % loop_length` means `k = some_n * loop_length + r` for some value `some_n` (including perhaps 0). So `m = k + loop_length - r`.

Comment: (contd.) **slow is `loop_length - r` ahead of the fast** so it'll take `loop_length - r` steps for the fast to catch on to the slow, so they will meet, somewhere. And the total number of steps will be `m = k + loop_length - r`.

Comment: Aha! I think I understand it :) To summarise, fast first travelled (2k:= ) `k` (non-loop) and is then `r` steps into loop. At this point, slow is at cycle point and is `loop_length - r` ahead of fast. Fast will catch up with slow in exactly `loop_length - r` steps. Hence, `m = # of steps for pointers to meet; => m = k + (loop_length - r)`. This on substitution also yields, `some_n factor of loop_length`.

Comment: Also, after this its trivial to also find out the length of a linked list which has a loop in it :). I wish I could upvote more !

Comment: Glad to help, now I understand it better myself. :) Well, since you asked, :) you could set up a bounty, and after 24 hours award it to an answer of your choosing. But that's not necessary, really.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. This kind of problem is tough to explain unless you are talking face to face. I will give it a try.

First of all in step 6: I think the fast pointer should be `k` distance away from the circle point.

But leave all that. We now have two cars. A fast car at twice the speed the speed of slow car.

Suppose the fast car starts in circular track at `k` distance away from circle point.

And the slow car starts from the circle point.

Now I am saying that both car will meet at `k` distance before the circle point.

Why? Because initially the fast car is at `k` distance from circle point. The fast car will cover `n` distance when completing the circle first time. Now the fast car is again at k distance from the circle point. But the slow car is at `n/2` distance from circle point.

Now the fast car has to cover `n-2k` distance more to reach `k` distance before the circle point. And slow car has to cover `n/2 - k = (n-2k) / 2` distance to reach `k` distance before the starting point. `Which is exactly half the distance of the path to be covered by the fast car`. And fast car is at twice the speed of the slow car.

So obviously they will meet at `k` distance before from circle point.

Comment: One thing I'd like to point out is, once inside the loop, fast will never overtake slow pointer. They will collide. Here's why: slow is at i and fast is assuming at i-1. when they move, slow=> i+1 and fast will be at i+1 too, hence collision. OR, slow is at i and fast is at i-2. next move, slow-> i+1; fast: i. next move, slow-> i+2, fast: i+2 and hence collision again. so fast will never be able to overtake slow, only collide once inside the loop!